# Apple Magic Mouse not staying connected to MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro

My Apple Magic Mouse has no issues staying connected with my 2013 iMac. However, with my 2019 MacBook Pro it loses connection on and off every 1-2 hours. I've unpaired, restarted, changed batteries, etc. Any ideas what the issue might be?

Comment: The Magic Mouse is known for its batteries occasionally loosing contact. It helps to put a small folded piece of paper between to stop them from moving in the case. Did you try that already?

Comment: I read that somewhere and did try it. Like I mentioned, it has no issues at all when I'm using with my iMac, so it doesn't seem like the batteries are the problem.

Comment: Does your MBP have any USB 3 peripherals? The Magic Mouse is Bluetooth. Bluetooth is very susceptible to interference from WiFi (2.4 GHz) and from USB 3. Do the iMac and MBP use different WiFi networks, or is the iMac on wired networking?